# How to create a regex that recognizes the following sample string format in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have this document full of ddls and I need to split each item by the tableName, ColumnName, ColumnDefinition, and Nullabilty.
For table name I have already developed a ddl like this but for the columns I am having trouble finding a regex
`table_name_match = re.search(r"(\w+)\s+\(", ddl)`

For Example I have a for loop splitting each file like this:

```
Sample_TBL
    ( sample_col1         decimal(10,0)    Not Null,
     sample_col2          decimal(10,0)    Not Null,
     sample_col3          char    Not Null
    ):
```

And I want to place them into variables like this.

```
for column in columns:
    column_name = column[0].strip()  (ex: sample_col1 )
    column_definition = column[1].strip() (ex: decimal(10,0) )
    nullability = column[2].strip() if column[2] else "Null" (ex: Not Null )

    print("Column Name:", column_name)
    print("Column Definition:", column_definition)
    print("Nullability:", nullability)
`
```

I have this for column pattern at the moment, however it is picking up table name and messing up what it is picking up.

```
column_pattern = r"\b(\w+)\s+([^(,]+)\s+([^,\s]+)"
```

Comment: There's a SQL parser library for Python, wouldn't that be more appropriate?